# Having trouble configuring custom domains on Xervo

Tags: node.js, meteor, appcontainer

I have a meteor project deployed on Xervo [here](https://utl-95476.app.xervo.io). I have a domain bought from GoDaddy, ustechland.com. I'm configuring custom domains in my project's administration panel on Xervo.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boOVF.jpg)
*.ustechland.com means all subdomains of this domain will point to this project. Now when I hit ustechland.com in the address bar, the URL changes to the project URL (https://utl-95476.app.xervo.io), which I don't want to happen.

I have configured CNAME records in my GoDaddy's domain DNS as specified by the Xervo Docs [here](https://help.xervo.io/customer/portal/articles/1700863-custom-domains).

Here is my list of CNAME DNS Records in GoDaddy:
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mELG3.jpg)
Although, the Xervo custom domain docs specify to add two CNAME records, I'm able to add one CNAME record with www subdomain pointing to Joyent Servo in US-East. Another record with naked domain (@) must be added pointing to the same. But I'm not able to add this record as GoDaddy says the record already exists.

Now, is the URL changing because I'm not able to add the CNAME record required? Do try hitting ustechland.com or www.ustechland.com and see the URL change.

And at times, both these URL's take me to 'Future home of something quite cool' page.

Answer (score 0):

I have found several sources that claim that godaddy does not support root cname flattening (which is what you want).

Check out these ideas for how to deal with this.

[CNAME Flattening With GoDaddy.](https://www.google.com/amp/www.befreeandwealthy.com/2016/12/27/use-flattening-cname-with-godaddy/amp/)
[Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-my-Go-Daddy-domain-to-point-to-my-app-hosted-on-OpenShift)

Good luck!